# Phpmyadmin и Расширение mysqli

Tags: php, debian, phpmyadmin

Не могу заставить работать phpmyadmin.
работало. всегда ставлю все обновления ибо stable debian 7.
в очередной раз при запуске вместо стартовой страницы у меня пошел на скачку файл phpmyadmin.

> Долгими установками переустановками всего что можно добился вот чего:
>   Расширение mysqli|mysql не найдено. Пожалуйста, проверьте ваши
>   настройки PHP. Смотрите our documentation для дополнительной
>   информации.

debian7
php5 переустанавливал.
другие страницы php грузятся если без sql
если с sql то

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in
>   /var/www/bla.php

Что то намудрено с модулями php.
apt-get purge и чистка руками не помогла

phpmyadmin сейчас из архива, но с apt-get install то же самое.

Comment: вам нужен пакет php5-mysql, а не просто php5

Answer (score 1):

То что мне нужен был php5-mysql это и так понятно. Я ставил и php5-mysql и php5-mysqlnd  но mysqli так и не подгружался.
Помогла замена папок etc/php5 и etc/apache2 с аналогичного сервера.
Выходит дело было в настройках, только в каких я так и не разобрался.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

Comment: Автор вроде пишет, что устанавливал php5-mysql, но этого не было достаточно для решения.